# Docker with nginx

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm new to working with nginx.

I'm using a VPS to run my container. My problem is that I apparently cannot configure the Docker container correctly to work correctly with nginx.

**This is how I set up the nginx configuration**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain domain;

    return 301 domain$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.domain domain;

    return 301 domain.com$request_uri;

    ssl_certificate /etc/path_to_my_сertificate
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/path_to_my_сertificate

    location / {
        proxy_connect_timeout 150;
        proxy_send_timeout 150;
        proxy_read_timeout 150;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8443;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

**Here is my command to start the container**
docker run -d -p 443:8443 --name=name -v /etc/path_to_my_сertificate:/ssl name

I'm grateful in advance for any possible answers.

Perhaps I should use a different approach to solve this. I will be grateful for your help

Comment: What error did you receive?

Comment: @Moziii I get listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use. Apparently nginx listens to this port

Comment: When you run a Docker container and map its ports using `-p 443:8443`, Docker tries to bind the host's port 443 to the container's port 8443. If port 443 is already in use on the host (by Nginx, in your scenario), Docker cannot bind to this port, leading to the error you're experiencing.

Comment: @Moziii Thanks, I thought about that, but how should I route requests to nginx then? If I try to specify -p 8080:8443 then it is pointless as the requests simply don't go through to nginx

Comment: Modify the Docker run command to use a different host port that is not in use. For example: `docker run -d -p 8444:8443 --name=name -v /etc/path_to_my_certificate:/ssl name`

Then, in your Nginx configuration, change the `proxy_pass` directive to point to the new host port: `proxy_pass http://localhost:8444;` . If you want to run your Docker container on port 443, you need to stop the other process (Nginx or any other) that's using this port.